# Why am I not getting the value from onChange with Select?

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

Testing part of a form. So, right now I just want to alert what the user selects:

JS:

```
function getData(title)
{
     alert(title);
}
```

HTML generated by PHP:

```
<select name="currentList" onChange="getData(this);">
     <option value="hat">Hat</option>
     <option value="shirt">Shirt</option>
     <option value="pants">Pants</option>
</select>
```

when I change the value I get an alert with:

[object HTMLSelectElement]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try `alert(this.value)`

Comment: that was it! Been doing a lot of AJAX so the small stuff starts to escape me. lol! I'll Accept the answer once the time limit runs out. Thanks!

Comment: Just remember, this will alert the `select`'s value. You should see BalusC's answer if you want to get the value of the selected option.

Answer (score 12):

With `this` you're passing the [HTML select element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement) to the function, not the value of the selected option. To obtain the value of the selected option, you need to get the selected option from the `options` by `selectedIndex` and then get its `value`. In a nutshell:

```
function getData(dropdown) {
    var value = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you could be concise with alert($("#currentList").val());, as long as you add the id="currentList" to the select list. This way you don't have to pass "this" to the onchange function.

Comment: i tried that first. Issue is my form is being created dynamically. Jquery would handle it only if my select box was static on the page. Once I made it part of a dynamically changing form it stopped recognizing it.

Comment: You would have needed to attach the event handler to the document (or some other container element that will always be present) using on, with a selector for your dynamic element.

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
alert(title.value)
```