# Using onchange with a drop down list selection box

Tags: javascript, php, onchange

I am having some trouble with an onchange event. The task is a large section of code for sorting data but to try through isolating code ive tracked it down to the onchange event not actually working and I cant see whats wrong.

```
<?php   include("db_connect.php"); 

$query = 'SELECT * FROM db_class_catagories';
$result = mysqli_query($dbconnection,$query);
?>


<select id="primary_catagory" name="primary_catagory" onchange = "test_function(this)"style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:10px;width:315px;height:20px;z-index:11;text-align:left;">
<option value=''>Select</option>
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    echo "<option value='" . $row['primary_catagory'] . "'>" . $row['primary_catagory'] . "       
</option>";}
?>
</select>

<?php
function test_function($primary_catagory)   {
echo $primary_catagory;
}
?>
```

This list is being generated from a database and is being called perfectly well, but no matter what I select nothing will happen. The main script used AJAX but again nothing was occuring and all I could think of is the onchange is not sending data.

I was using this example but couldnt get it working. [How can i populate a dropdown list by selecting the value from another dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18526914/how-can-i-populate-a-dropdown-list-by-selecting-the-value-from-another-dropdown)

My task is more or less the same but something is not right with my onchange, any idea what daft thing im missing? thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `onchange` event is a browser event, so `test_function()` must be a JavaScript function.  It could use Ajax to send information about the selection to a server-side PHP listener, but the `onchange` event must be handled at the client.

There is a simple example here: [Why am I not getting the value from onChange with Select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597456/why-am-i-not-getting-the-value-from-onchange-with-select)  Just put your Ajax call where the alert is (in the answer, not the question.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, `test_function` is in PHP on the server, and `onchange` is on the client/browser.  They cannot talk directly to each other.

Try adding some Javascript (and jquery) to the html page.

```
 <script>
 function test_function(e) {
     $.getJSON("server.php", {
         "action": "save",
         "val": $(e.currentTarget).val()
     }
 }
 </script>
```

Now the inching event will execute this javascript function, which will load that server.php page in the background.

(this is untested code)